# How can I Solve Angular Issue I have Run command "npm cache clean -- force "

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './cache'
Require stack:

- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules\ajv\lib\ajv.js
- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\registry.js
- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\index.js
- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\json\index.js
- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\experimental\jobs\simple-registry.js
- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\experimental\jobs\index.js
- D:\CameraApp\Cctv-Analysis\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\experimental.js

Comment: Have you used `--forrce` (like in the title) or `--force`?

Comment: Sir i have used --force when i run using ng serve it gives above error

Comment: In that case try to reinstall everything in your project with `npm install`

Comment: Try deleting the node modules and package.lock file and run a fresh npm install

Comment: Thanks,@Batajus and @user3929590